# How do I upload file through custom field, save it to database and get it

Tags: custom-field, uploads, videos

I have made a custom field without any plugin. When I choose file I want to upload that file and get its url on my page. Basically, I want to upload video and show it on frontend. This is my code right now (its just good for text, not upload file):

```
function cd_meta_box_cb()
{
    global $post;
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $text = isset( $values['my_meta_box_text'] ) ? $values['my_meta_box_text'][0] : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text">Video URL</label>
        <input type="file"
       id="my_meta_box_text" name="my_meta_box_text" id="my_meta_box_text"
       accept="video/*" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />
       <input type="hidden" class="hidden-file-field" name="hidden_file_field" />
    </p>
    <?php    
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() 
        )
    );
    if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_text', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text'], $allowed ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the file to the WordPress Media Library, you can use [`media_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/). The function returns the attachment post ID on success, so you can save that in a post meta and then use the relevant function to get the attachment/file details, e.g. [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/) can be used to get the attachment URL.

So for example:

- In `cd_meta_box_cb()`, this will add the file upload input and (for demo purpose) displays the current video URL, if any, before that input:

  ```php
  <?php
  $video_id  = (int) get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_video_id', true );
  $video_url = $video_id ? wp_get_attachment_url( $video_id ) : '';

  echo 'Current video URL: ' . esc_url( $video_url ) . '<br />';
  ?>
  <input type="file" name="my_video_file" accept="video/*" />
  ```
- In `cd_meta_box_save()`, this will add the video to the media library and save the attachment (post) ID in a post meta named `my_video_id`:

  ```php
  if ( isset( $_FILES['my_video_file'] ) ) {
      // Add the file to the media library.
      $video_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_video_file', $post_id );

      // Save the video/attachment ID in a post meta.
      if ( ! is_wp_error( $video_id ) ) {
          update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_video_id', $video_id );
      }
  }
  ```

And if you just wanted to upload the file to the WordPress uploads directory (`wp-content/uploads`), i.e. *without* adding the file to the media library, then you can use [`wp_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/), but please check the documentation for usage syntax and also examples.

Comment: Amazing. Reached my goal here. Thanks a lot.